# How to permanently block all incoming connections in the macOS firewall?

Tags: network, macos, firewall

I have the default macOS firewall enabled with stealth mode and block all incoming connections option set. And I have it locked. But after a while, the firewall is in green state with selective blocking and not block all connections.

How to identify which application is changing the firewall state? I have another admin user in my system, but I have remote login option disabled. I think this user is responsible for system change. I have removed that account meanwhile, but still want to know how to identify firewall state changes.

Is it possible to get an alert or something when the state changes?

Edit: It is not related to the admin account. After removing it, still this senario happens.

Figured. It is the policy applied. JAMF.

Comment: Please don't post a possible answer (JAMF policy) in your question. Instead write a proper answer with some details/some explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to install [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index-de.html), a tool that helps you to identify and control any incoming and outgoing traffic and what it was initiated from.

Note that I assume it is not advisable to completely block *any* incoming traffic.